# Sharing view languages across stores module

Tags: multistore, language, multidomain

I'm having the following problem. Take a look at my demo store configuration.

```
www.store1.com
    store 1
             language 1
             language 2
    store 2
             language 2
             language 3

www.store2.com
    store 3
             language 1
             language 3
    store 4
             language 2
             language 5
```

These stores / languages share products. They also share language. I'm looking for a way to define 1 language across all the views who have this product. So i'm talking about translation of a product by selecting the store or view. Now my client have to add this translations double which is a bit annoying.

So if i add a product language at store1.com -> store 1 -> language 2 it should be available at store2.com -> store 4 -> language 2.

I have seen all the posts about creating a custom modules or working with observers and so on but i'm looking for an existing solution. And i know they are around i just can't find it anymore. I have seen it before. Anyone knows what i mean? Or maybe some other suggestion on doing this without spending too much time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry guys! The second i hit post my co-worker walks in giving me this. So here's the thing i was looking for haha.

http://www.sellxed.com/shop/en/magento-store-view-configuration-sync.html